# How to create s3 client object using Session token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to upload a file to s3 using certificate credential. Is it possible to get client object of s3 bucket using certifcate?

Initially I tried to upload a file using below,

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                              aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, file_name)
```

Now, I do not want to use ACCESS_KEY|SECRET_KEY to create client object because this is running on edge device. Instead of that I have generate certs (IOT). I want to use this certificate to create client object. So, at the end I have temporary ACCESS_KEY|SECRET_KEY|SESSION_TOKEN. I want to pass these temporary credential to create client object. How to do this in boto3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution,
It's quite simple, we just need to pass `aws_session_token`

```
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN)
```